# Объявление переменной типа RECORD в объекте

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Хочу создать объект с переменной типа record внутри, пишу код:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE someType_t AS OBJECT
(
  connection UTL_TCP.connection

) FINAL;
```

Выдает ошибку: Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_TCP.CONNECTION' must be declared

Гранты на UTL_TCP есть

[image: select * from user_tab_privs]

Если объявить переменную этого типа в анонимном блоке, то всё ок

```
declare
  connection UTL_TCP.connection;
begin
  null;
end;
```

Версия: *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если указать полное имя типа, то сообщение об ошибке будет более понятным:

```sql
create or replace type tcpconn as object (
    conn sys.utl_tcp.connection
);
/
```

> PLS-00329: schema-level type has illegal reference to SYS.UTL_TCP

Нельзя использовать типы данных обьявленные не на уровне схемы.
Для переменных с PL/SQL типом данных воспользуйтесь пакетами:

```sql
create or replace package util_tcp as
    function  getConnection return utl_tcp.connection;
    procedure setConnection (conn utl_tcp.connection);
end;
/
create or replace package body util_tcp as
    conn_ utl_tcp.connection;
    function  getConnection return utl_tcp.connection is
    begin
        return conn_;
    end;
    procedure setConnection (conn utl_tcp.connection) is
    begin
        util_tcp.conn_ := conn;
    end;
end;
/
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: Пожалуйста, но вы и сами разобрались, может ещё кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась банальной - SQL не поддерживает PL/SQL типы данных для аттрибутов объектов.

Comment: немного уточнил формулировку, вы не против?